# Can't figure out how to make a function for creating new users into the database

Tags: javascript, html, database, mongodb, api

I am new to working with databases. I've been trying to create a login/register webpage using only HTML, Js and MongoDB in my codes in order to practice. I have successfully made a function for login, yet I've been struggling to create a function for registering using the Fetch API.
I am aware that my register code is used rather for a login function, but I used it as a template for the sign up one.
I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me fix the register function using Fetch() in order to not give me 401 and  to be able to add the new user's email and password to my database. Thank you.

```js
 const btnAccount = document.querySelector('.account .submit')

 btnAccount.addEventListener('click', event => {

        event.preventDefault()

        const email = emailAccount.value
        const pass = passAccount.value
        const pass2 = pass2Account.value

        if (email && pass && pass2) {
          if (pass === pass2) {
          
            // The data i wish to add to my mongoDB users database:
            const account = {
              strategy: "local",
              email : emailAccount.value,
              password: passAccount.value
            }

          fetch('http://localhost:3030/authentication', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(account)
          }).then(response => {
            return response.json()
          }).then(result => { 
          
            console.log(result)
            document.forms[1].reset();
            
          })
          .catch(err => {
          // If I got some errors regardings the DB or in the code itself:
            console.log('eroare:', err)
            alert(`Something's wrong. I can feel it!`)
          })
          }
          else {
          // Passwords not the same:
            alert('Parolele nu coincid!')
          }
        }
        else {
        // Not all fields written:
          alert('Completeaza bah campurile...')
        }
      })
```

```html
<main>
      <form class="account">
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input required type="email">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input required type="password" class="password">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password2">Verify Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="password2">
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="submit">Create new account</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="existing-account">I already have an account</a>
        </div>
      </form>
      <button class="fetchItems">Load ITEMS</button>
      <div class="output"></div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Can you show the codes on the end point that you call here `http://localhost:3030/authentication` ?

Comment: There are no other url-s besides index.html.

Comment: What do you mean? When you call `http://localhost:3030/authentication` there has to be something there to process your data and return the result to this index.html

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Feathers.js. I used it to create the services. I have a file called authentification.js. Can't post all it's content in a single post. Here is a screenshot of the code: https://imgur.com/6kIrSjv

Comment: Generally 401 error is auth error from backend side. Have you tried calling that url in something like postman?

Comment: Yes, i did. It gives me "Invalid authentication information"

Comment: You should have mentioned in your question that you're using Feathers.js and posted the relevant codes which is what you captured and upload in imgur. That way people will have a better understanding of your problem. As for the answer, I have read a little bit of their docs and I think you have to take out `authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());` from your codes as it is expecting a `jwt token` while you're only providing `local` strategy

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand the problem myself and I am a newbie with login/register pages. Is there anything else I should do? I am still receiving 401 at the register form.

Comment: Oh wait, register? I thought you're trying to login an existing user. So you're trying to register using login function? That won't work even if you are using it as a placeholder because it's fundamentally different. Try to create a new route and I don't think you need to use auth service for register. Simply take the value from the client, sanitize it, and insert it into your DB